# Ubuntu with Java Error

Tags: software-center, java

I have Oracle Java installed on my computer. Latest version 1.7 and path variables set properly. But most applications in Ubuntu from Software Center that require Java needs Open JDK Iced Tea etc. I want to install applications in Ubuntu without installing any other versions of JDK/JRE. How's that possible.

**EDIT**

Just giving you an example. I have Oracle Java(JDK 7) installed but when I want to install Netbeans via Software Center it is asking to install Open JDK. Netbeans I had to install directly via downloading the binaries. Similarly many other softwares exist.

Comment: What applications are you referring to that require OpenJDK rather than Oracle's Java? (Oracle bought Sun Microsystems a year or so ago).

Comment: @ClivevanHilten just giving you an example. I have Oracle Java(JDK 7) installed but when I want to install Netbeans via Software Center it is asking to install Open JDK.

Comment: Basically any java driven application from the software centre lists openJDK as a dependency, I have the same issue. For netbeans download the official installer off their website.

Comment: @handuel I did that. but that's not the only case. I downloaded one deb file for another package that has java as dependency. And am helpless as the Ubuntu version is in deb format.

Comment: I think there is a .sh installer, I'll go hunting

Comment: just let me know. i feel Ubuntu developers need to address this as being a Java Developer I need prefer Oracle's Java.

Comment: To install netbeans without a .deb enter this line by line in terminal: pastebin.com/h2TFrGsK I've also posted an answer which should let you use suns java but have openjdk installed.

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar Oracle has even said OpenJDK is a suitable replacement.  I've also heard rumors they may drop support for Linux with their Java.  They should both work equally well, OpenJDK and Oracle Java.

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar You could do with reading the community documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Answer (score 2):

Try installing openjdk, but using `sudo update-alternatives --install /path/to/suns-java/java 1` `sudo update-alternatives --config java` from the terminal to set suns java to the default. (You may also have to do the same for javac, javaw and javaws).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu supports OpenJDK out of the box. Leave OpenJDK installed. This way installing software that rely on Java will not reinstall OpenJDK each time.

After installing Oracle Java 7, use your environment variables and the Ubuntu alternatives system to configure Oracle JDK as the default.

When installing software like NetBeans you will have to consult the Netbeans documentation and specifically configure Netbeans to work with the Oracle JDK instead of OpenJDK. Some software detect your default Java from the environment variables while others don't.

Here is a blog entry that installs Oracle Java 7 using the Ubuntu alternatives system: http://hendrelouw73.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-update-21-on-ubuntu-12-04-linux/

Here is a link to the update-alternatives command: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-alternatives.8.html